# how to know the start time/end time of Python subprocesses Popen running in parallel

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, subprocess, python-unittest

I am running subprocesses in parallel to test race condition, to know the number of conflicts, i want to know the start time/end time of each subprocess, here is my code:

```
processes = []
for x in range(8):
    processes.append(subprocess.Popen(["my task"], stdout=f))
for p in processes:
    p.wait()
```

8 subprocesses run in parallel and I can see the conflicts, but how would I know the exact start time/end time of each subprocess? Because I need them to calculate how many conflicts exist.

Answer (score 0):

I have a quick and dirty solution - print the time and process identifier at the beginning and ending of each process. You may need to send the identifier to each process to let them know who they are, though.

Comment: but my commands are all the same, not sure how to define the key

Comment: You need to learn how to use 'args' for a process - how to send them to a process and how the process loads them.